# Ford figo 2010 starting problem

Tags: ford, starting, figo

My ford figo diesel not starting . Fuel pump overhauled , it is showing  pressure when tested in machine . After fitting it is not starting . If starts rev going up and down 1000 to 1500 rpm and after few mints engine stops . Injectors checked . Engine checked in lathe for compression leakage pistons with rings are new . Fuel pump relay in fuse box located behind globe box checked , also been exchanged with same  one . Ignition switch when put in 2nd position 8 beeps heard .  Checked with digonasis tool everything showing ok only abs sign is not going off .Still engine is not starting . Please suggest me where I have  to look through to solve the problem thank u

Comment: Did this problem only start after the fuel pump overhaul?

Comment: No , I had changed piston and rings with bearings after fitting the engine it started and was running 3 hrs .during servicing of clutch suddenly it stopped and was not starting . Diagnosed by ford digonasis machine said no fuel. Pressure  so the pump was overhauled after fitting the problem still remains . So replaced the pump with a pump from running engine still the same problem remains

Answer (score 0):

I know back in the day ford had a reset button in the trunk. After you check that,replace your fuel filter. Very inexpensive.